# JavaScript / HTML - new Audio JavaScript fails in IE 8 and less?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

How can I fix this? eg:

---

```
snd = new Audio("foo/bar.wav")

alert("abc") //in IE this line wont run??!

snd.play()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Audio not working in ie7 or ie8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827637/html5-audio-not-working-in-ie7-or-ie8)

Comment: ik, but anyway to fix that line ?

Comment: The `alert()` will work fine in IE.

Comment: no ie stops at "snd = new Audio("foo/bar.wav")"

Comment: If you put the `alert()` before the `snd = `, it will work fine. The `new Audio` is causing the error, which is preventing execution of the rest of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you detect the feauture (the supported type),
your script will not throw an error in other browsers (mobile etc.), 
that doesn't support audio.

You could make it crossbrowser conditional ie.

```
if (typeof window.Audio != 'undefined') { 
  /* var snd = new Audio("foo/bar.wav"); ... */ 
}
```

or consider to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).

Answer (score 0):

IE8- does not support the `<audio>` element. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio. If you can separate your script, you can do this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script>
    alert("Old IE.");
  </script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
  <script>
    snd = new Audio("foo/bar.wav");
    alert("IE9");
    snd.play()
  </script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
  <script>
    snd = new Audio("foo/bar.wav");
    alert("Not IE (Or IE10+)");
    snd.play()
  </script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

IE10 drops conditional comments altogether, so it will use the `!IE` script.

Comment: Yeh, but how can I make only IE ignore that line ?

Comment: So it won't get stuck aat that line

Comment: Which line, the console or the audio? IE8 won't understand either.

Comment: if the script is inline, in a `<script>` element, you could use conditional comments to make IE ignore it.

Comment: I would appreciate if the person who downvoted by answer would leave a comment why.

Comment: @Mich' Can you split out the audio part and put it in a separate script tag?

Comment: This answer should be a comment. It doesn't explain how to fix it, and neither do your comment suggestions. The correct answer is to use polyfills, if you intend to use either feature, since they are not cross-browser compatible. Conditional comments are the last thing that should be suggested for this kind of problem

Comment: @Mich' Try the example I just put up

Comment: You're right about the audio element, but IE8 does support `console.log()`.